# Custom Map for DiGraph::Arc LEMON

Tags: c++, graph, hashmap, lemon-graph-library

I want to create a custom map to assign different weights to different arcs.

```
struct MyMap{
            typedef int Value;
            typedef ListDigraph::Arc Key;
            unordered_map<Key, Value> mapping;
            Value operator[](const Key& e) {return mapping.at(e);}
        };
```

But I get an error in the mapping search, saying:

```
In template: type 'const std::hash<lemon::ListDigraphBase::Arc>' does not provide a call operator
```

I cannot use the standard maps of LEMON, since I cannot pass them between functions and I cannot have them as attribute of class.

How can I do it ?

Comment: The error message means that you must define a hash function for your `unordered_map`. See duplicate for details.